# Git merge entre branches com submodules

Tags: git, versionamento

Tenho um seguinte projeto mobile.
Um repositório onde o código é compartilhado entre vários projetos. Chamarei esse repositório de base.

Nos projetos foram criadas branchs desse repo base pois era necessário adicionar um submódulo diferente para cada projeto.

Ex.:
Projeto 1. Criada a branch projeto1 no repositório base e adicionado o submódulo sub1.
Projeto 2. Criada a branch projeto2 no repositório base e adicionado o submódulo sub2.

Então... a diferença entre o master e as branches no base é que as branches possuem submodule.
Só que ao longo do desenvolvimento, a branch projeto1 foi modificada e eu preciso mandar essas modificações para o master e para a branch projeto2.

Estando na branch master e executando um git merge projeto1, ocorre que o submódulo do projeto1 é incluído no master, e isso não pode ocorrer, pois o master é apenas para servir de base para os projetos.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, faça o merge com o parâmetro `--no-commit`:

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit projeto1
```

Nesse momento, o merge terá sido feito, mas ainda não terá sido realizado o commit. Aproveite agora para remover o submódulo:

```
git rm caminho/do/submodulo
```

Talvez seja necessário usar o `git submodule deinit` primeiro -- a documentação parece indicar que não é necessário, mas nunca removi um módulo.

Uma vez feito isso, continue com o merge usando `git commit`.

Pronto. O merge vai incluir a remoção do submódulo.

A partir de então, você vai poder fazer merges normalmente, desde que não tenham sido feitas alterações no submódulo. Alterações no submódulo provavelmente vão resultar em merge conflicts, o que permitirá a você interceder na hora de fazer o merge. Se não for o caso, você vai ter que repetir o procedimento acima sempre que houverem alterações no submódulo.

Comment: Daniel. Mas caso eu tenha que depois enviar essa atualização para as outras branches? Ex.: modificações na branch projeto1, merge em master, remoção do submódulo e depois merge disso em projeto2. Será que funcionará perfeitamente?

Comment: @LucianoLima Se você mandar coisas do master para os branches, então você vai ter o problema inverso -- o merge vai remover o submódulo. A solução nesse caso é fazer a mesma coisa nos dois sentidos: primeiro o merge para o master removendo o submódulo, e logo em seguida você usa o mesmo procedimento para fazer merge do master para o branch adicionando o submódulo de volta. Depois disso, merges nos dois sentidos vão preservar a situação do submódulo naquele branch.

Answer (score 3):

O interessante neste caso é sempre que for fazer uma alteração, criar um branch a partir do master porque daí você pode mergear com qualquer outro branch sem levar os submódulos. Ficando:

```
master
|----- projeto1
|-------- projeto2
|- novo branch
```

Depois de criar a atualização, faz o merge deste novo branch no projeto1, projeto2 e no master. Depois de mergear no master pode até apagar este branch novo.

Para resolver seu problema pontual, acredito que a melhor solução seja utilizar o comando cherry-pick. Nele você aplica commits (independente de qual branch estiver) no branch atual.

Seria algo como:

```
$ git cherry-pick <hash do 1º commit a enviar>..<hash do ultimo commit a enviar>
```

Segue link da documentação de como utilizá-lo:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Gostei da sua solução Lucas.
Porém não sou eu que vou fazer isso. Se fosse faria do jeito que sugeriu, mas o meu colega que está nesse projeto é super preguiçoso e não vai querer criar novas branches por dificultar os testes. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão: crie um branch novo a partir do branch "projeto1", e então remova o submódulo nesse branch novo, e aí sim, finalmente, faça o merge do branch novo no branch master (e em seguida no "projeto2").

Mais ou menos assim:

```
git checkout projeto1
git branch temporario
git checkout temporario

git submodule deinit caminho/do/submodulo
git rm caminho/do/submodulo
git commit -m "Submódulo removido"

git checkout master
git merge temporario
git branch -d temporario

git checkout projeto2
git merge master
```

Comment: Vou testar essa alternativa. Me pareceu a mais simples para atualizar o master.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez uma melhor forma de organização seja você transformar o que chama de base em um submódulo e os branches do projeto em novos repositórios que utilizaram o submódulo base.
Dessa forma, as correções no código comum seriam mais facilmente compartilhadas entre os projetos.

Caso não seja viável, sugiro fazer um rebase de seus commits nos branches, para separar os commits que fazem alterações no código base, dos commits que fazem alteração no SHA-1 dos submódulos. Tendo esses commits separados você pode traze-los para o branch master usando o comando cherry-pick, como sugeriu o Lucas.

Comment: Eu não dei a situação por completo, mas na verdade é assim:
Repositório principal possui 2 submódulos:
-sub1 possui 1 submódulo:
--base possui 1 submódulo:
---resouces
-sub2 possui 1 submódulo:
--base possui 1 submódulo:
---resouces

Essa é a configuração original, mas o base é o único que é compartilhado entre projetos e possui, em cada projeto, um resources diferente.